# Class of subsets of positive integers and all subsets of positive integers in the form $\{n,n +1,\dots\}$

Tags: general-topology

Hi I've got a problem on topology.

> Let $\mathcal T$ be the class of subsets of positive integers consisting null set and all subsets of positive integers of the form $E_n =\{n,n+1,n+2,n+3,\dots\}$ with $n$ element of positive integers.
>
> 1. Show that $\mathcal T$ is a topology on the set of positive integers.
> 2. List the open sets containing the positive integer $G$.

Could you please help me?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried verifying that this collection satisfies the axioms of a topology?

Comment: So our sets are $E_n = \{x \geq n:x\in \mathbb{N}^+  \}$. What is the union of $E_n$ and $E_m$ when $n<m$? What about the intersection?

Comment: Since you are new to this site, you could maybe read this: [How to ask a homework question.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)
I wrote this comment because the question sounds homework-like.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to check that

   - the null set is in $\mathcal T$, which is assumed;
   - $\Bbb N^*$, the whole set, is in $\mathcal T$, which can be seen taking a particular value of $n$;
   - the intersection of two elements of $\mathcal T$ still is in $\mathcal T$. It's clear when one of them is the null set, otherwise, writing $S_n:=\{k\in\Bbb N^*,k\geq n\}$, we have $S_n\cap S_m=S_{f(m,n)}$, where you have to find $f(m,n)$;
   - an arbitrary union of elements $S_i,i\in I$ of $\mathcal T$ still is in $\mathcal T$. You can assume that none of these elements is the null set. Then show that $\bigcup_{i\in I} S_i=S_{\min_{j\in J}j}$.
2. The open sets are given; surely the null set won't work. Can you see which $S_j$ will work?